# off topic autocomplete suggestions

Tags: intellij-idea

Can't remember when, but a while ago IntellIJ started to show suggestions in the autocomplete suggestions that seem off topic. Very often the "wrong" suggestion gets to the top of the list and ends up in the code. This starts to get annoying. ;-)

I wonder where it is coming from (what language is it?) and why does it shows up editing java files?

Example:

Starting to type, `CTRL+Space`, suggests:

[image]

Pressing `Enter` inserts:

[image]

This is just a single example it happens here and there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have some non-default [live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) configured? E.g. in this example the template has the `fina` abbreviation.

Delete them from your configuration for the IDE not to offer them in completion.

Comment: Thanks, the live template hint helped. I went through the list and found `find_all` in the ruby section. After disabling ruby it seems to be gone. Still strange that IDEA would show that in java files.

Comment: `Still strange that IDEA would show that in java files.` IDE shows this based on the **Context** configured for the live template. It means this template had `.java` files added to possible contexts.

Comment: I see, found the Context settings. The ruby templates are enabled "everywhere". Do you know if this is the default? I don't see a ruby context.